# What was lab.msdn.microsoft.com?

Tags: msdn

I've seen some links to [lab.msdn.microsoft.com](http://lab.msdn.microsoft.com/), but now all it does is give a standard ASP.Net error page.

What did the site use to have, and when did it go down?

Comment: Try http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://lab.msdn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but is it [Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/)?